# md-autocomplete ordering dropdown items

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, md-autocomplete

I have a md-autocomplete field:

```
<md-autocomplete md-selected-item="videoInfo.lineUp[1]" md-items="item in searchQuery(searchText1)" md-search-text="searchText1" md-item-text="item.display" md-floating-label="Loosehead">
    <span md-highlight-text="searchText1">{{item.display}}</span>
</md-autocomplete>
```

I populate `md-items` with

```
$scope.searchQuery = function (searchText) {
    var users = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.users,
        function (value, key) {
            // value = user object
            // key = userId
            var dN = value["display_name"];
            if (dN) {
                var obj = {};
                obj[key] = value;
                obj["display"] = dN;
                if (dN.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
                    users.push(obj);
                }
            }
        });
    return users;
}
```

Is there a way to order the items in the dropdown alphabetically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
md-items="item in searchQuery(searchText1) | orderBy : display"
```

Comment: I accepted too early, it doesn't work... Any other tips?

Comment: There are demo on angular-material, which works with that filter. Could you provide demo, which doesn't?

Comment: Where can I find that demo? Where can I make a demo that includes the angular material libraries?

Comment: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete you can use codepen links from that page to create your own

Comment: it should be `orderBy : 'display'`. If you modify your answer I can accept it again

Answer (score 3):

```
md-items="item in querySearch(searchText) | orderBy : 'fieldName'"
```

Worked for me !!